# Read locally stored JSON file with IDE (Node)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to use my javascript IDE (webstorm) to parse some large JSON files I have stored on my computer (~500 megabytes). Is there anyway I can tell node to access this file? I know node can access JSON files through http requests and I wonder if a similar principle may apply to files (as I can link to files in chrome as such: `file:///C:/Users/...`). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a local file you can do this:

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/your/path/to/json.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

Now depending on what you plan to do with the data, you can parse or stringify it.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I had no idea the node file system even existed!